# SSAS Tabular Measures: Do staged facts from DW need to be expressed in DAX as measures to use as measures?

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, data-warehouse, ssas-tabular

I have a SQL DW that has staged facts -- already aggregated -- to the granularity of multiple dimensions.

For example these dimensions:

- Period
- Product
- BranchLocation

And this fact:

- Revenue (aggregated sum per period x product x branch)

When I bring this into a SSAS Tabular model, deploy it, and try to use it (say in Excel, for example), I am confronted with the realization that my facts must be expressed as measures. I say this because I cannot use the fact as a value in a pivot table in Excel.

Is there a simple way to convert or cast each *already aggregated* fact into measures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to convert or cast each already aggregated fact into measures?

Sure.  Just create simple measure for each fact.  You can take it a step further and hide the fact column from client tools, so that only the Measure appears.  You need to specify how the model will further aggregate this fact in the measure expression.  EG

```
Sales = sum(FactResellerSales[SalesAmount])
```

Note that Measures are only *required* by some clients (like Excel), that use the MDX interface for the model.  Power BI reports support using pretty much any column anywhere on a report.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It makes perfect sense (including the part about hiding the fact column), but when I do that I get a grand total of all the revenue amounts for all the records. This grand total appears not only in the measure grid in the designer, but also as the value in each cell in a simple pivot (i.e. Branch (row) by Quarter (cell)). It seems like I need to define the measure as a sum of each combination of dimensions?

Comment: The most common reason for seeing a grand total where you expect a slice is a problem with the model relationships.  If a slicing column doesn't have a "filter flow" path to the table with the columns referenced in the measure, you get a grand total instead.

Comment: Eureka! Thank you.